# How to prove the cumulative distribution function of the maximum of a pair of values drawn from random variable X is the square of the original CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X=Y^2$, where $Y\sim U(0,1)$. Now we need to find the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

$$P(X<x)=P(Y^2<x)=P(Y<x\sqrt x)=F_Y(x\sqrt x)$$

That's all?

Comment: why anyone will upvote this as this is just a problem statement

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Actually, I want to edit this statement but could not. I am very new to this platform. I will be highly grateful if you can help me with this concept. Thanks for your attention and comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This was an answer to the original question:*

> "How to Prove that the cumulative distribution function of the maximum of a pair of values drawn from random variable X is the square of the original cumulative distribution the function of X?"

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed then

$P(\max(X,Y) \le z)$

$= P(X \le z \text{ and } Y \le z) $

$= P(X\le z) P(Y \le z) \text{ because they are independent}$

$= \left(P(X\le z)\right)^2 \text{ because they are identically distributed}$

---

*With the revised question:*

> Suppose $X=Y^2$, where $Y\sim U(0,1)$. Now we need to find the cumulative distribution function of $X$.  $$P(X<x)=P(Y^2<x)=P(Y<x\sqrt
> > x)=F_Y(x\sqrt x)$$ That's all?

$P(X\le x)=P(Y^2 \le x)=P(-\sqrt x \le Y \le \sqrt x)$ which is $F_Y(\sqrt x)$ since $Y \ge 0$.

Comment: So above statements prove the cumulative distribution function of the maximum of a pair of values drawn from random variable X is the square of the original CDF, right?